Assemble list of all permutations of a given strftime-substituted string over a daterange
I want generate speculative filepaths to logfiles which the user can define using generic strftime formatters like so:
User input (config file):
"/mnt/bulkdrive/api_archive/api*.company.com/log.restart%Y/api_queries%Y%d.log"

Now I want to come up with all possible file paths where the formatters are replaced by the   according date for a given timerange. The smallest timestep that I want to cover is 1 day.
How can I determine all permutations without yielding doubles in an efficient way?
The very costly way would be to walk through the timerange day by day, substituting the formatters for that date and check if the result string is already present in an ordered set. The other way I could think of was to hash every resultstring and put it into a hashmap. Is there a better solution?
